# How do I send a request with superagent that uses the same query parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

I am trying to make a request against a php server that is constructing the url like this:

website.com/?q=help&q=moreHelp&q=evenMoreHelp

How do I use superagent to pass the same query with multiple values?

I've tried this:

req.get('website.com').query({q:'help',q:'moreHelp',q:'evenMoreHelp'}).end(...)

But I'm not sure it is actually sending all three 'q' values.  What am I supposed to do to make sure they all get sent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You definitely will not see all three `q` values when you pass the query in the manner you are trying, because you are making a JavaScript object there and yes, there will only be one `q` value:

```
$ node
> {q:'help',q:'moreHelp',q:'evenMoreHelp'}
{ q: 'evenMoreHelp' }
```

Superagent allows query strings, as in this example [straight from the docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#get-requests):

```
request
  .get('/querystring')
  .query('search=Manny&range=1..5')
  .end(function(res){

  });
```

So if you pass the string `'q=help&q=moreHelp&q=evenMoreHelp'` you should be okay.  Something like:

```
req.get('website.com').query('q=help&q=moreHelp&q=evenMoreHelp').end(...)
```

If this is too ugly, you can try (WARNING: I have not tried this):

```
req.get('website.com')
 .query({ q: 'help' })
 .query({ q: 'moreHelp' })
 .query({ q: 'evenMoreHelp' })
 .end(...);
```

Comment: Using a query string appears to have solved my issue. Now I just need to convince the php server to give me a proper api so I don't need to pass the same key multiple times.

Comment: It is proper and a common practice for an api to take multiple instance of the same key. It's just not so easy to do it with native js objects.

Answer (score 2):

As of [Superagent 1.5.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases/tag/v1.5.0) you can pass an array as a property of the query object and it will generate multiple query parameters of the same name:

```
req.get('website.com').query({foo: ['bar1', 'bar2']})
```

results in `website.com?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`

As a side note, if you want Rails `parameter[]=value` syntax then the following works for me:

```
req.get('website.com').query({'foo[]': ['bar1', 'bar2']})
```

Comment: When I use the `.query({foo: []})` syntax with only one element it passes it as a string. I had to use the `.query({'foo[]':})` syntax to force it to pass it as an array.

Answer (score -2):

I can confirm that passing the parameters as an array into the query works great, like so:

```
query: {
      productId,
      orderStatuses: ['FOO', 'BAR', 'OTHER'],
    },
```